# How to convert arabic digits to numeric in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, numbers, encode

Params include arabic digits also which I want to convert it into digits:-

```
"lexus/yr_٢٠٠١_٢٠٠٦"
```

I tried this one

```
params[:query].tr!('٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩','0123456789').delete!(" ")
```

but it gives an error

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError Exception: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
```

for that I do

```
params[:query].force_encoding('utf-8').encode.tr!('٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩','0123456789').delete!(" ")
```

how I can convert this?

Comment: What is the input? If its a form you can set `accept-charset="UTF-8"` to ensure that the inputs are treated as UTF-8.

Comment: as i mention above inputs are in arabic digits

Comment: Yes but from where?

Comment: form textfield...

Comment: `force_encoding` won't fix your encoding if it's flat-out wrong in the first place. Check your bytes to be sure you're getting the right data. For what it's worth `params[:query].force_encoding('utf-8').encode.tr('٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩','0123456789').delete(" ")` is fine. Don't chain methods like `tr!` as they often return `nil`. Instead assign the result to something.

Comment: "how can I convert this?" convert what to what, does that `force_encoding` line still throw the same error, or the digits aren't being replaced as you expected or?

Comment: @SimpleLime i mention in question , my purpose is to convert arabic digits into integers. I show all issues in doing that

Comment: i want to convert this string str = "lexus/yr_٢٠٠١_٢٠٠٦" into "lexus/yr_2001_2006"

Comment: _Sidenote:_ don’t use banged versions of methods unless you fully understand the circumstances and really _want to mutate_ the original objects. BTW, using unbanged versions in your second approach would solve an isuue.

Answer (score 4):

If you have enforced UTF-8 encoding then this should work fine.

`str = "lexus/yr_٢٠٠١_٢٠٠٦"`

`str.tr('٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩','0123456789')`

returns `"lexus/yr_2001_2006"`

ASCII 8-bit is not really an encoding.  It is binary data, not something text based.  Transcoding ASCII 8-bit to UTF-8 is not a meaningful operation.  I would recommend ensuring that the request that passes the `query` parameter through your textfield is using valid string encoding, if you can control this.  You can use `String#valid_encoding?` method in ruby to check you are receiving a correctly encoded string.

Comment: “ASCII 8-bit is not really an encoding”—what? Even ASCII 7-bit is _really_ an encoding. Try `"foo".force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT).encoding #⇒
 #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>`. This encoding was used since AD and is literally the same as `Latin1`.

Comment: Open to correction, but my understanding is as follows:
ASCII 8-bit infers that you COULD BE dealing with binary data, i.e. raw bytes, and not only text-based data.  I concede if you can guarantee you have only 7-bit characters in your ASCII 8-bit data then it's fine because any 7-bit ASCII is valid UTF-8, correct? Perhaps I should have said: ASCII 8-bit is not really a valid "text-only encoding"?